# How do I track re-visitors on my website to push promos?

Tags: javascript, cookies, ip-address, ads

I am a newbie and my requirement is to push promos to re-visitors (who didn't order anything on their first visit).

I couldn't find much help online(other than articles on google analytics).

Any help or direction towards right sources is appreciated.

Comment: Cookies are delicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you plan to store data. But as a cheap and simple way, you can accomplish this with javascript and setting localStorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Depends where/how your site is rendered. If you're client-side rendering you could use `localStorage` or cookies, but if you're server-side rendering you're going to need to go the cookies route.